# Appcelerator Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications events not firing on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I need to implement PushNotification for iOS device.

The error message this when I want to subscribe a channel
Missing fields. Required: device_token and channel

I have apple certificate and all configurations in Appcelerator dashboard.

And when I am running the app on my device app asking to confirm push notification.

I believe the error appears because of Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications events not firing.

Here is my code.

```
var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");

login();

function login() {

env = Ti.App.deployType.toLowerCase() === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
username = Ti.App.Properties.getString('acs-username-'+env),
password = Ti.App.Properties.getString('acs-password-'+env);

// Places your already created user id credential
Cloud.Users.login({
    login : username,
    password : password
}, function(e) {
    if (e.success) {

        var user = e.users[0];
        Ti.API.info(' Login Success:\n' + 'id: ' + user.id + '\n' + 'sessionId: ' + Cloud.sessionId + '\n' + 'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\n' + 'last name: ' + user.last_name);

    } else {
        Ti.API.info('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message)));
    }
});

}

var deviceToken = null;

// Check if the device is running iOS 8 or later
if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {

    // Wait for user settings to be registered before registering for push notifications
    Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('usernotificationsettings', function registerForPush() {

        Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush);

        Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
            success : deviceTokenSuccess,
            error : deviceTokenError,
            callback : receivePush
        });
    });

    Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
        types : [Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE]
    });
}

// For iOS 7 and earlier
else {

    Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
        // Specifies which notifications to receive
        types: [
            Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
            Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
            Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
        ],
        success: deviceTokenSuccess,
        error: deviceTokenError,
        callback: receivePush
    });
}

function receivePush(e) {
    //Ti.API.info('Received push: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}

function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
    deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
    Ti.API.info("eeeeeeee" + e);
    //subscribeToChannel();
}

function deviceTokenError(e) {
    Ti.API.info('ssssssssFailed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}

function subscribeToChannel () {
    // Subscribes the device to the 'news_alerts' channel
    // Specify the push type as either 'android' for Android or 'ios' for iOS

    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken({
        device_token: deviceToken,
        channel: 'news_alerts',
        type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'android' : 'ios'
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Ti.API.info('Subscribed');
        } else {
            Ti.API.info('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message)));
        }
    });
}

function unsubscribeToChannel () {
    // Unsubscribes the device from the 'test' channel
    Cloud.PushNotifications.unsubscribeToken({
        device_token: deviceToken,
        channel: 'news_alerts',
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Ti.API.info('Unsubscribed');
        } else {
            Ti.API.info('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message)));
        }
    });
}

setTimeout(function() {
    subscribeToChannel();
  }, 6000);
```

Comment: Are you sure you getting device token? And also make sure that you have created this **channel: 'news_alerts'**  on Appc Dashboard before registering users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before making calls to Arrow DB, make sure your deviceTokenSuccessCB is getting fired and since you have indicated that it's not getting fired then you can below steps for it:

- Your iOS device settings are ON for your app's notifications.
- You are not using LiveView ON mode as it's a known issue here [LiveView ON iOS Notification issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23533)

Comment: Thanks! LiveView is the problem in my case.